# Cannot obtain Bean using @Autowired / WebApplicationContext.getBean()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-framework-beans

I'm pretty new to Spring and this code is based on different tutorials, so keep that in mind when continuing to read please.

So this is the task:

I'm creating a web frontend on top of an existing web service using SpringMVC which runs on Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.

The frontend simply shows some database tables, nothing fancy.

I tried using the `WebapplicationContext.getBean()` method with a result of a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException for the controller.
It's cause is a java.lang.NullPointerException in the line I'm trying to autowire my bean.

Therefore I was searching on Stackoverflow and google for someone with a similar issue, couldn't find any suitable post.

Here are my classes.

@ComponenScan Class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.xyz.webservice.services", "com.xyz.webservice.web"})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired //this works fine
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

//--> the error
    /* this doesn't work
    @Autowired
    private GridService gs;
    */
    //neither does this work
    private GridService gs = (GridService) ctx.getBean("gridService");
//<--


    @RequestMapping(value= {"", "/", "/index"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showIndex(ModelAndView mv,
            HttpSession session) {
        Grid grid = getGrid();

        ...

        return mv;
    }

    private Grid getGrid() {
        return (Grid) ctx.getBean("grid"); //this works totally fine
    }
    ...
}
```

Service

```
package com.xyz.webservice.services;

@Service
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class GridService {
    ...
}
```

POJO

```
package com.xyz.webservice.web;

@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Grid {
    private List<String> columnNames;
    private List<Page> pages;
    private int currentPageNumber;
    private CrmEmsHistoryProperties sortedBy;
    private boolean isSortedDescending;

    //Getters and Setters
```

The GridService provides the methods to work with the Grid.
Therefore the Controller injects both, the Grid (by using ctx.getBean("grid");), which works fine and the GridService, which doesn't work at all.

Expected result:
The controller should be able to inject the GridService from Spring's IoC-Container.

Actual result:
The controller is not able to inject the GridService from Spring's IoC-Container.

WebApplicationContext.getBean() throws this exception:

```
[8/13/19 12:23:17:785 CEST] 0000008b ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [dispatcher] in application [WebserviceEAR]: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gs'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xyz.webservice.services.GridService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:345)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:637)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xyz.webservice.services.GridService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 42 more
```

@Autowire throws this exception:

```
[8/13/19 12:14:35:106 CEST] 00000086 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [dispatcher] in application [WebserviceEAR]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController' defined in file [/home/abc/Repositories/JEE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/Webservice/WEB-INF/classes/com/xyz/webservice/controller/IndexController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.xyz.webservice.controller.IndexController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:345)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.load(ServletWrapper.java:1378)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1027)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.xyz.webservice.controller.IndexController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
... 37 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xyz.webservice.controller.IndexController.<init>(IndexController.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
... 39 more
```

Hope somone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work, because in Bean lifecycle construction occurs prior to dependencies injection, hence at the moment of `gs` initialization `ctx` is not yet injected and is equal to `null`

```
private GridService gs = (GridService) ctx.getBean("gridService");
```

Instead you should do it in following way

```
private GridService gs;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
     gs = (GridService) ctx.getBean("gridService");
}
```

Method will be invoked after all injections, so initialization of `gs` will occur correctly.

Comment: As for not functioning `@Autowired private GridService gs;` - I can't say for now. Injection itself seems OK. Make sure that you import proper annotation class (`org.springframework.stereotype.Service`). Also make sure that all dependencies (if any) are properly injected into GridService itself.

Comment: the explanation makes sense, there are no dependencies in GridService and its the proper annotation class but that doesnt fix it

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my local environment and it worked using constructor injection

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {   

    private final GridService gs;

    public IndexController(GridService gs) { this.gs = gs; }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Then you must add more information to your question, maybe we are missing some details. Try to implement a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example